# Stream CSV data in Kafka-Python

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, kafka-python

Am sending the CSV data to Kafka topic using `Kafka-Python`. Data is sent and received by Consumer successfully. Now am trying to stream a csv file continuously, any new entry added to the file should be automatically sent to Kafka topic. Any suggestion would be helpful on continuous streaming of CSV file

Below is my existing code,

```
   from kafka import KafkaProducer
   import logging
   from json import dumps, loads
   import csv
   logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


   producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='127.0.0.1:9092', value_serializer=lambda 
   K:dumps(K).encode('utf-8'))

   with open('C:/Hadoop/Data/Job.csv', 'r') as file:
   reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter = '\t')
       for messages in reader:
       producer.send('Jim_Topic', messages)
       producer.flush()
```

Comment: Does it have to be Python? For ingest/egress Kafka Connect is generally a much better approach. If that would be useful I can provide an answer based on it

Comment: @RobinMoffatt, yes please provide me the answer using  Kafka Connect, will utilize it

Answer (score 1):

Kafka Connect (part of Apache Kafka) is a good way to do ingest and egress between Kafka and other systems, including flat files.

You can use the [Kafka Connect SpoolDir connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-spooldir/connectors/csv_source_connector.html) to stream CSV files into Kafka. Install it from [Confluent Hub](https://www.confluent.io/hub/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir), and then provide it with configuration for your source file:

```sh
curl -i -X PUT -H "Accept:application/json" \
    -H  "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors/source-csv-spooldir-00/config \
    -d '{
        "connector.class": "com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.spooldir.SpoolDirCsvSourceConnector",
        "topic": "orders_spooldir_00",
        "input.path": "/data/unprocessed",
        "finished.path": "/data/processed",
        "error.path": "/data/error",
        "input.file.pattern": ".*\\.csv",
        "schema.generation.enabled":"true",
        "csv.first.row.as.header":"true"
        }'
```

See [this blog](https://rmoff.net/2020/06/17/loading-csv-data-into-kafka/) for more examples and details.